# How do I display fields from other parent object on related list?

Tags: related-list, junction-object

I have a juction object linking two objects together like this---

A - junction object - B

I am trying to show Fields from object A on the junction object related list on object B.

I am only able to add the fields from the junction object in the related list. Is there a way to show the fields from the other parent (ie - object A) in the junction object related list on object B?

I know I could use formula fields to pull the data onto the junction object and then display them on the related list but is there any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways :

- Formula field
- Custom Inline VF page

If you are ready to compromise on related list field visibility and prioritize reports, then its possible on reports without creating any new field.